# Operating a GitHub pull request on Android Studio

Tags: github, android-studio, merge, pull-request

I can't manage to find a simple way to initiate a merge from a pull request in Android Studio, where everything else concerning github is quite well implemented.
The only way I have found is to enter the console instruction they give on GitHub in Git Shell, and to switch back to Android Studio after that to merge.

Did I miss a simpler way to do that ?

Comment: I would work through github desktop. If you haven't already downloaded it, you should.

Comment: Two years later I am now an adept of the console for using git. I find it more reliable and understandable than most embedded or graphical tools that are around. 
It is also very well documented and you won't have any trouble getting help would you have problems. So this is not really an answer to the question but more an advice.

Answer (score 6):

1. Click right button on the tree project or code editor.
2. Select Git menu.
3. Select Repository menu.
4. Select Pull menu.

The window Pull Changes will open. Then select Pull button.
Check out the images below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The simpler way is to install the GitHub plugin from File...Preferences/Settings...Plugins.  Restart if necessary.  Then, under File...Preferences/Settigns...Version Control, there will be a GitHub section.  Initialize it with your GitHub credentials and server.

Then, under VCS...Git there will be 2 new menu items at the bottom: Create pull request and Rebase my github fork.

The create pull request command will give you some options and even redirect you to the web interface if you like.  Super convenient.

Comment: Why do you need down vote? As you read through instruction, its simple and clear.

Comment: @IPKaal because it didn't have anything to do with Github, which was in the title and the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in the VCS menu, then choose git, then branches. After selecting the branch with the pull request, click on merge.